# How to conform normal directions of a roof

Tags: geometry-nodes, normals

I want to scatter roof-windows with geometry nodes and i have the problem, that my normals are pointing in different directions. It is driving me crazy but its probably a easy fix. I simply wan't that the y axis is pointing to the peak on both sides of the roof, like in the second picture. How can i archive this in a smarter way than i have right now?

Thanks in advance :)

[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Align $z$ to normal, then rotate $y$ around $z$ to point up:

[image]

[image]

Comment: .. because, luckily, rain comes from the sky...

Comment: Thank you very much :)