# Align euler to vector problem

Tags: geometry-nodes, vector

I am trying to instance a collection on each face of a mesh, and rotating each instance to align each instance to normal of face, but alignment gets broken if mesh has other than standart orientation

[image]

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: There is nothing to really show or provide, the main reason of the problem is: if i am using instance on points, and points are generated in the middle of each face, it loose some data, even if i store it and use as rotation a bit further, but if i use the points of mesh themself then alig euler works as intended.https://imgur.com/a/8ceqv4v

Comment: Like all the "tutorials" or and "lessons" on that problem provide a cone or a cyllinder for that task, but noone use some more complex mesh, where local z rotation is crucial, and if i want to  feed for instance some custom randomized rotateion, it brings only more mess.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/301831/60486

Comment: (duplicate confirmed by OP on Discord)